# Listen to multiple port httpd fedora

Tags: http, fedora

how to set httpd to listen to multiple port just like in apache `ports.conf`

I wanted to add some virtual host that will be available only on some ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the default config file:

```
vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf <-- requires root privileges
```

and add:

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
....
Listen 8x
```

Now, for the vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName server1 <-- this needs to be in your /etc/hosts file
     DocumentRoot /var/www/project1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:81>
     ServerName server2 <-- this needs to be in your /etc/hosts file
     DocumentRoot /var/www/project2
</VirtualHost>
```

After this, make sure to restart httpd:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart <-- requires root privileges
```

Finally, access the two sites like: `http://server1:80`, `http://server2:81`

Update:
Fedora also requires an update to the SElinux policy, allowing httpd to access non-default ports (like 90, for instance):

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 90 <-- requires root privileges
```

Comment: tried adding Listen 90 and restart http got this error `Job for httpd.service failed. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` also I can't find `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Perhaps port 90 is already used. Check if anything turns up for `netstat --tcp`

Comment: just for testing, change server1 and server2 to localhost and see if that works

Comment: you also need to update the SELinux policy: `semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 90`

Comment: Happy it worked out. I'll update my answer to include the semanage part

Answer (score 0):

**On Fedora 29**

save you the headache

Make sure that you have added the port on the `firewall-cmd` command

`sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=<port>/tcp`

When adding a `Listen <port>` to your httpd.conf make sure that `SELINUX` is not `Enforcing`

there is no `SEMANAGE` on `Fedora 29` unlike the older ones

```
#check if selinux is enforcing
> getenforce
Enforcing

#If enforcing turn it off
> sudo setenforce 0

#check again if we successfully turned off enforcing
> getenforce
Permissive

#Now we start httpd
> sudo systemctl start httpd

# return selinux to enforcing
> sudo setenforce 1
```